# Stacking arrays in ndim (fourth axe) and applying rotations with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I have written the following snippet in order to stack 3D arrays along a fourth axis, to apply rotations along this axis.
Is there numpy functions to do that:

```
* something similar to numpy.dstack but in ndim
* numpy.apply(4D Array, axis=3, angles=[0, 60, ...])
```

The shape of the array mentioned in the code is: (114, 79, 2)

```
print np.ndim(c1), c1.shape
#stack1=np.concatenate((c1,c1,c1,c1), axis=3)#DOESN'T WORK
s = c1.shape
n = 4#new axe depth
newshape =(s[0],s[1],s[2],n)
stack1=np.zeros(newshape,dtype=int)
print np.ndim(stack1), stack1.shape
stack1[:,:,:,0]= c1
stack1[:,:,:,1]= c1
stack1[:,:,:,2]= c1
stack1[:,:,:,3]= c1
# Now apply a transformation along the fourth axis:
#the rotation angle should vary along the fourth axis ...
#np.apply_along_axis(nd.rotate(??),3,stack1)
for a,n in zip([0,60,120,180],[0,1,2,3]):
    stack1[:,:,:,n]=nd.rotate(stack1[:,:,:,n],a, reshape=False)
```

Comment: What is `nd.rotate`?

Comment: Do you mean this function? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html#scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate

Comment: Yes, I mean scipy.ndimage.rotate(array, angle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.array` 'stacks' arrays along a new first axis; transpose can move the new axis to the end:

```
In [1040]: c1=np.ones((2,3,5),int)
In [1041]: c1s=np.array([c1.copy() for i in range(4)])
In [1042]: c1s.shape
Out[1042]: (4, 2, 3, 5)
In [1043]: c1s.transpose([1,2,3,0]).shape
Out[1043]: (2, 3, 5, 4)
```

I could also use `concatenate` if I first add a new axis to each component

```
In [1044]: np.concatenate([c1[...,None].copy() for i in range(4)],axis=-1).shape
Out[1044]: (2, 3, 5, 4)
```

The `concatenate` variants, `vstack`, `hstack`, `dstack` all use some sort of iteration over the `args` list to adjust their dimensions in preparation for concatenation.

```
vstack: concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
hstack: arrs = [atleast_1d(_m) for _m in tup]
dstack: concatenate([atleast_3d(_m) for _m in tup], 2)
```

But why stack/concatenate in the first place?  Just iterate over a list of arrays:

```
alist = [c1, c2, c3, ....]  # plain list
for a,n in zip([0,60,120,180],[0,1,2,3]):
    alist[n]=nd.rotate(alist[n],a, reshape=False)
```

And if you are going to 'stack' arrays, and then iterate over them, it make more sense to do that along the 1st axis, not the last.  That way it iterates over contiguouous blocks of data.  With strides numpy does a good job of iterating over any axis, but iteration over the 1st is it's 'natural'

You probably can do the iteration without a counter:

```
arr = np.array([c1,c2,...]):
for c in arr:
    c[:] = nd.roate(c, a, reshape=False)
```

(MATLAB places the 'outer' axis last, numpy places it first).

Answer (score 2):

In the new version of Numpy (1.10.0) there is a `stack` function for ndimensional stacking. However, if that is not an option, here is a function that would work for stacking:

```
import scipy.ndimage.interpolation as interpolation

def create_stack(*arrays):
    return np.asarray(arrays).swapaxes(0, -1)

stack = create_stack(c1, c1, c1, c1)
for n, a in enumerate([0, 60, 120, 180]):
    stack[:, :, :, n] = interpolation.rotate(stack[:, :, :, n], a, reshape=False)
```

Comment: So there's no way to avoid a loop and to use a vectorized code?